# How can I count how much each different values occur in each column independently?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

Given table mytable with two columns letter and num

```
letter|num
------+------
a     |1
a     |1
b     |1
b     |2
```

I tried doing

```
SELECT letter, count(letter), num, count(num) from mytable group BY letter, num;
```

but it returns

```
letter|count|num   |count
------+-----+------+-----
  b   |  1  |  1   |  1
  a   |  2  |  1   |  2
  b   |  1  |  2   |  1
```

whereas I wanted

```
letter|count|num   |count
------+-----+------+-----
  a   |  2  |  1   |  3
  b   |  2  |  2   |  1
```

Is this possible to do, and can I do it in one query?

Comment: The expected output, `COUNT(num)` doesn't make sense?

Comment: Not really: what if you have 14 different letters but just 3 numbers? You can't capture this output. You example works **only** because you have 2 of each

Comment: Does not make sense. Why the first record of your expected answer lists letter 'a' and number '1' ? Are they related? What if I have 3 letters and two numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I meant it makes sense in that what I want doesn't make sense. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change it to 2 separate aggregates like this.

```
SELECT 'letter' as type, letter AS item, count(letter)
    from mytable group BY letter
UNION ALL  --CAST to be same type as letter
SELECT 'num', CAST(num AS varchar(100)), count(num)
    from mytable group BY num;
```

Comment: You read my mind. That was my intended output. I didn't really know what I wanted until I tried your code out. Thanks a bunch. Cheers.